# Need for a JavaScript/ecma262 ToInt32 algorithm explanation

Tags: javascript, math, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, integer-arithmetic

I'm trying to understand how JS engines convert a JS Number (Float64) to a 32-bit signed integer. I read that one can quickly convert a 64 bit float to a 32 bit signed integer with the bitwise OR like:

```
-8589934590 | 0 // which gives 2
```

I can't understand where does the 2 come from. According to the [spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/11.0/index.html#sec-toint32), the ToInt32 algorithm does this (the bold text is mine, not the spec's):

1. Let *number* be ? ToNumber(argument): **-8589934590 is already a Number**
2. If *number* is NaN, +0, -0, +∞, or -∞, return +0.: **No**
3. Let *int* be the Number value that is the same sign as number and whose magnitude is floor(abs(number)): **-8589934590 is already an integer**
4. Let *int32bit* be *int* modulo 2³² **Since 2³² is positive the result should also be positive. In JS the remainder operator uses the sign of the left operand, so to get a modulo in this case (where -8589934590 is negative), we negate it:** `let int32bit = 8589934590 % 2**32 // 4294967294 which has 32 bit length 0b11111111111111111111111111111110`
5. If *int32bit* ≥ 2³¹, return *int32bit* - 2³²; otherwise return *int32bit*. **int32bit is smaller 2³¹ (since it's negative), so I use** `int32bit` **which equals** `-2` (**Even if we consider** `0b11111111111111111111111111111110` **an unsigned integer, then it's greater 2³¹ and *int32bit* - 2³² still equals** `-2`

*Could someone, please, explain, do I correctly understand the ToInt32 algorithm and the bitwise OR operator?*

Comment: @JonasWilms as I understand, since the modulo gives the sign of the right operand and % gives the sign of the left one, they can be used to substitute each other, but with caution. As I understand this `-myNegativeVar % positiveInt` is equivalent `myNegativeVar modulo positiveInt`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your step 4 is wrong. Modulo is defined by the spec as:

> The notation “x modulo y” (y must be finite and nonzero) computes a value k of the same sign as y (or zero) such that abs(k) < abs(y) and x-k = q × y for some integer  q.

So -8589934590 is our x, and 2**32 is our y, from that we also know that k must be positive. If we choose q = -1 we can solve the equation to k = -4294967294. That is however *not a valid solution*, as k (negative) does not have the same sign as y (positive). If we choose q = -2 instead, we get k = 2.

So for negative numbers x and positive numbers y, q * y will always have to result in a *smaller number* than x for k to be positive. Thus if we are transforming that to positive numbers (like you did), we are looking for the *larger multiple of the number* not *the smaller one*. E.g. if we take 2 % 3, that'll return 2 (2 - 2 = 3 * 0), whereas -2 modulo 3 will return 1 (-2 -1 = 3 * -1).